# Network detects trojan on my device, Malware/avast can't find it.

Tags: windows-10, virus, trojan

I am a new uni student, I got an email from my uni network that they have detected Win.Trojan.Hadsruda on my laptop (they sent my mac address). And if I don't remove it in one day, they will lock my wifi out.

I have windows 10, I ran malware bytes and avast scans and nothing came up. I asked the front line techie of IT and he suggested getting a windows reset (while keeping files) because these trojans can't be detected easily.

Q1) Could it have been a false positive? Though I did get a request to update bit lord - which somehow 'crashed' and didn't go through 30 minutes before that incident.

Q2) Whats a suitable software to find and remove it

Q3) Is resetting preferrable? Can't trojan put it's tentacles in .doc and other non executable files?

Comment: Contact your the computer help desk at your university.  Don't ever trust emails! Or even forward that email to an email that you yourself find from your university website and ask them if they send emails like that and if it is genuine.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, it is possible that it is a false positive, but I'd guess that it isn't.
2. here is the MS advice for this particular malware. it does look like windows defender and the MS security scanner products can both deal with the strain as identified. https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Program%3aWin32%2fHadsruda%21bit
3. Yes, in general malware can hide in other files, or take more invasive actions to preserve itself. This does not appear likely with this particular strain of malware however. that behavior would be more common in RASKits or other persistence malware, but not so common in an advertising bot.

Note that this is more of a "Potentially unwanted program" adware issue, so its not seriously trying to hurt you, but linking into bad advertising networks is in itself a dangerous proposition, so it really is to be avoided. It does seem like your bitlord installation is likely related.